# Chakra UI Menu is not displaying under the text

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I trying to make a navigation bar with Chakra UI, but the **`Menu`** isn't showing out in the correct place

[description text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB7Yk.png)

```js
import { Flex, Image, Link, Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuList, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Component, ReactNode } from "react";

export class NavigationBar extends Component {
  render(): ReactNode {
    return (
      <Flex flexDir={"row"} justifyContent={"right"}
        alignItems={"center"}>
        <Link marginRight="auto">
          <Image src="https://cutiecat6778.github.io/cdn/blog-logo.png" />
        </Link>
        <Menu>
          <MenuButton as={Text}>
            Topic
          </MenuButton>
          <MenuList maxW={"200px"} borderRadius={0} padding="0">
            <MenuItem>
              Life in europe
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
              Daily
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
              Programming
            </MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
        </Menu>
        <Link ml="40px">
          Random
        </Link>
        <Link ml="40px">
          Về tôi
        </Link>
      </Flex>
    )
  }
}
```